# PHP to Coldfusion zip/pkpass output stream

Tags: php, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11, lucee

This project is apple wallet project I have but in PHP code im facing challenges not much help is available around my PHP question are open no response so far anyway now I decided to convert in coldfusion.

Im able to save ZIP/PKPASS file in binary in BLOB. When im sending PHP API GET Request to fetch card(binary zip/pkpass) it is returning me binary stream see attach screen below.
[image]

same result I want to achieve in coldfusion when I'm sending request to coldfusion API code also attached below.

POSTMAN:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

im trying to convert PHP code in coldfusion(lucee). Binary code in database which is zip file but extension is '.pkpass',database field name is "data".

when im running coldfusion code it is giving error "Corrupted Content Error".

PHP code :

```
 $myPass = $result->fetch();

        $data = $myPass['data']; //zip/pkpass file Binary code from DB
        $nameFile = 'passbook_'.time().'.pkpass';
        file_put_contents($nameFile, $data);

        $stream = function () use ($nameFile) {
            readfile($nameFile);
        };

        return $app->stream($stream, 200, array(

            'Pragma' =>  'no-cache',
            'Cache-Control' => 'private,false',
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding' =>  'binary',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.basename($nameFile).'"',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.apple.pkpass',
            'Content-length' => filesize($nameFile),
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.$nameFile.'"',
            'Last-Modified' => gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T')
        ));
```

Coldfusion Code : NOT WORKING Need assistance

```
   <cfset filename = getPass.serial_number&'_'&createUUID()&'.pkpass'>  
            <cfheader name="Pragma" value="no-cache">
            <cfheader name="Cache-Control" value="private,false">
            <cfheader name="Content-Transfer-Encoding" value="binary">
            <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=#filename#">
            <cfheader name="Content-Type" value="'application/vnd.apple.pkpass">
            <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=#filename#">
            <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="#DateFormat(getPass.updated_at, "yyyy-mm-dd")#' '#TimeFormat(getPass.updated_at, 'hh:mm:ss')#">
<cfcontent type="application/x-zip-compressed" variable="#BinaryDecode(getPass.data, 'Base64')#"> <!--- Binary Data from db 'getPass.data' --->
```

Comment: Please elaborate on `not working`.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk i updated my question hope it will give clear idea now what im trying to accomplish thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem seems to be that you're putting the last modified value in a "Content-Disposition" header. Try fixing that and cleaning up the other headers as follows:

```
<cfscript>
filename = "#getPass.serial_number#_#CreateUUID()#.pkpass";
cfheader( name="Pragma", value="no-cache" );
cfheader( name="Cache-Control", value="private,false" );
cfheader( name="Last-Modified", value="#DateFormat( getPass.updated_at, 'yyyy-mm-dd' )# #TimeFormat( getPass.updated_at, 'hh:mm:ss' )#" );
cfheader( name="Content-Transfer-Encoding", value="binary" );
cfheader( name="Content-Disposition", value="attachment; filename=#filename#" );
cfcontent( variable="#getPass.data#", type="application/vnd.apple.pkpass" );
</cfscript>
```

Comment: @CFSimplicty thanks for quick response I removed the line <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=#filename#"> even same error you can see updated question look like im now able to stream binary data.  when im doing this?`<cfcontent type="application/vnd.apple.pkpass" variable="#BinaryDecode(getPass.data, 'Base64')#">`  it is able to give me download file but there is no content in file when I unzip do im missing something

Comment: You need the "attachment" Content-Disposition header (but not the "inline" one as well - use one or the other). The problem is/was with the 3rd Content-Disposition header which should be a "Last-Modified" header. You also shouldn't need to use `BinaryDecode()` as the `variable` attribute of `cfcontent` expects binary. Did you try the code I posted? It works for me on Lucee using a retrieved blob from the database.